# r: combine two separate values on same row based on duplicate values in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Let's say I have

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Gene.names  Case Control
  <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A1BG          52      NA
2 A1BG          NA      32
3 A2M           16      NA
4 A2M           NA      15
```

As you can see, `Gene.names` are duplicates and have corresponding values for `Case` and `Control`. I need to combine the values for `Case` and `Control` so they are printed on the same row for each `Gene.name`.

I am looking for a solution in `dplyr`.

**Expected output**

```
  Gene.names  Case Control
  <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A1BG          52      32
2 A2M           16      15
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(Gene.names = c("A1BG", "A1BG", "A2M", "A2M"), 
               Case = c(52, NA, 16, NA), Control = c(NA, 32, NA, 15)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                     -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Are duplicates guaranteed to only have one non `NA` value per column? If not how do you select which value to choose?

Comment: Yes, duplicates are guaranteed to only have one non `NA`

Comment: Yes,  `group_by(Gene.names) %>% fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>% slice(1)` was a solution.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `pivot_longer` and `picot_wider` will do this.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(
  Gene.names = c("A1BG", "A1BG", "A2M", "A2M"),
  Case = c(52, NA, 16, NA), Control = c(NA, 32, NA, 15)
), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -4L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



df |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = Case:Control) |> 
  filter(!is.na(value)) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   Gene.names  Case Control
#>   <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 A1BG          52      32
#> 2 A2M           16      15
```